Gitlab - How to deactivate pipeline from branch and its children
Is there a way to deactivate the pipeline from running on a certain branch and its children.
Example :

Parent_branch

Child_Branch1
Child_Branch2



I don't want the pipeline to run on the Parent_branch, Child_Branch1 and Child_Branch2.
I tried using Except but it does not to work.

have ou tried with "rules" ? you can do more specifics things than 'only' or 'except'.
There is many examples in the links bellow https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rulesif
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_rules.html#common-if-clauses-with-predefined-variables
GitLab set a lot of predefined varaibles that you can use in your pipeline definition
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html
Hope this helps
